# python usage of timeit library

Tags: python, timeit

I'm trying to measure the execution time of my Python functions using the `timeit` library, and I'm looking to obtain output similar to the following:

"193 ms ± 33.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)"

Here is my code:

```py
import timeit

def is_perfect(n):
    sum = 0
    for i in range(1, n):
        if n % i == 0:
            sum += i
    if sum == n:
        return True
    return False
```

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: `timeit` docs: Note: it's tempting to calculate mean and standard deviation from the result vector and report these. However, this is not very useful. In a typical case, the lowest value gives a lower bound for how fast your machine can run the given code snippet; higher values in the result vector are typically not caused by variability in Python's speed, but by other processes interfering with your timing accuracy. So the min() of the result is probably the only number you should be interested in. After that, you should look at the entire vector and apply common sense rather than statistics.

Comment: @David if the code doesn't depend on random input, else the average can be a good indicator